# When using JFrame, where does the add() method come from?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I've been roaming the Internet looking for an answer to this question, but have come up rather empty handed.

I'm following a JFrame practical from university, and using my lecture notes and the advice on the practical guidance sheet I have this basic code:

```
public HelloFrameMenu()
{
    message = "Hello, World!";
    label = new JLabel(message);
    label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, DEFAULT_SIZE));
    add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    createSouthPanel();

    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
}
```

This creates a text message on my JPanel and executes the createSouthPanel() method which works fine and adds some menu lists to the JFrame.

My question is regarding the add function. I don't understand what this is part of. I thought if it was a static method, its class name would precede it. As it doesn't, I assumed it was part of the JFrame package or one of the classes automatically loaded by Java, but I can't find the method in either.

Where does this method come from?
Why is it not preceded by anything?
What other methods can be used like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html), you will see that there is no `add` method in `JFrame`. However, several `add` methods are inherited from Container and Component, which are listed in the *Methods inherited from...* section.

Comment: Literally as you posted that I noticed it at the bottom of the Java API. Duh! Still, why doesn't it have to be preceded by anything? e.g. Container.add or something (please note I've NEVER used containers before).

Comment: @AndrewMartin Because JFrame is a subclass of Container, so it inherits all its methods automatically. It has nothing to do with containers or GUI, it is just the way inheritance works in Java.

Comment: Thanks - I clearly still have much to learn. I'll mark your answer as accepted when the time limit allows me, as you were the first to respond.

Answer (score 2):

[JFrame#add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29) is an instance method that is inherited from `java.awt.Container`. It is not preceded by any instance here as you have subclassed a `JFrame` directly. Normally you are not adding any new functionality to the frame so the preferred approach is to create an instance directly and use:

```
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
...
myFrame.add(...);
```

Check out the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) for all available methods.

Comment: Thanks for this - everytime I feel I'm beginning to move past the total beginner questions, something drags me right back in!

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it as "this.add" as it is an inherited member from Container.

Answer (score 1):

Class `HelloFrameMenu` would have to extend `JFrame` and the `add` method comes from [Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) and is used for adding visual components to the frame.  It would be more intelligible if `add` and `setSize` were prefixed with **super** (e.g. `super.add(...)`), which is what I always to to denote that the method comes from a superclass.

Comment: I agree - would help little noobs like me!

Comment: Not just noobs but anyone -- it is simply easier for grasping the code.  Especially if you have a narrow attention span (like everyone nowadays) :)  LOL

Answer (score 1):

It's to do with Inheritance.  Java is an object oriented language which means that (almost) everything is an object.

Objects can then be arranged in a hierarchy.
eg a Cat object might extend an Animal object. It inherits all the behaviour (methods) of Animal,  and can add its own.

In your case, JFrame extends Container and Container has an add method.